# database design / mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, erd

My client is wanting to add new functionality to their site, they deal with actors/models and want to be able to create a credit history for each of the clients (much like a CV or Resume).

They have some criteria that I must adhere too, and because of this I cannot get my head around it.

A credit can be one of two things, it can be a 4 column credit, or a single column credit. The credit however must have a category, and these categories can be one of the following, TV, Film, Advert, Radio or something of their own making.

The second criteria is that the categories are orderable, so for example if they are entering an actors credit, he may have television and film credits, they may from time to time, to film above television.

The third criteria is that the credits with each category are orderable, so film1 credit does not have to be at the top.

Here is what I have devised so far.

```
CANDIDATES     |      CREDITS  
----------            -------    
candidate_id^         credit_id*
                      credit_category  
                      credit_heading
                      credit_title  
                      credit_role  
                      credit_director
                      credit_position  
                      candidates_candidate_id^^
```

^ - Primary Key
^^ - Foreign Key

My confusion comes from using this table structure there is no way to alter what order the categories are in, as if I added a `credit_category_position`.

For example if the user has a credit in the category film, and I want to add another, when I insert the data through my form, how do I keep the credit_category_position consistent for all that clients film entries?

I hope this makes sense to someone.

Comment: if I'm reading that right, you need some kind of dynamic sorting to be done, based on what category a credit is in? What's the difference (besides the name) of a 4-column and 1-column credit?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the kind of ordering you are after.  Is the ordering the same for every actor?  Meaning will Film always be before TV?  Or can the order of categories be different for each actor?

Comment: @MarcB the difference is a 4-column credit has set criteria to fill in, heading, title, role + director, a 1-column credit you can just a paragraph of text.

Comment: @Matt The order is actor specific.

Answer (score 0):

I've just glanced through your question and I'm not sure I exactly understand it, but one thing just pops to my mind:

why don't you have a [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) between `candidates` and `credits`?

```
CANDIDATES     |      CREDITS  
----------            -------    
candidate_id^         credit_id*
                      credit_category  
                      credit_heading
                      credit_title  
                      credit_role  
                      credit_director


CANDIDATE_CREDIT_REL
--------
rel_id*
credit_id^^
candidate_id^^ 
credit_position
```

Comment: sounds like a good solution but how do I deal with ordering the categories...which are the credits parents?

Answer (score 0):

> A credit can be one of two things, it can be a 4 column credit, or a
>   single column credit.

I'm going to skip this one, because I don't understand it and because there isn't anything in your description that helps me with it.  Feel free to edit your question.

> The second criteria is that the categories are orderable

You need an additional table for that, because each candidate can have multiple credits in, say, film.

```
create table credit_category_order (
  candidate_id integer not null,
  credit_category <whatever> not null,
  category_order float not null, -- lets you reorder by splitting the difference,
                                 -- but there are other ways.
  primary key (candidate_id, credit_category),
  foreign key (candidate_id, credit_category) 
    references credits (candidate_id, credit_category)
);
```

> The third criteria is that the credits with each category are
>   orderable

Add a column to credits. When you query, join credit_category_order, and `ORDER BY credit_category_order.category_order, credits.credit_order`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Credit_Category
----------
id, category_name, details


Actor_cc_order  //For each actor, have an entry for every category
----------
id, id_actor, id_cc, ord_number


Actor_credit
------------
id, id_actor, id_cc, credit_details
```

view of credits

```
SELECT a.*, b.category_name, c.ord_number  FROM
Actor_credit a
JOIN  Credit_category b ON b.id = a.id_cc
JOIN  Actor_cc_order c ON c.id_actor = a.id_actor AND c.id_cc = b.id
SORT BY a.id_actor, c.order_number
```